# Explain Javascript RegExp Behaviour

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this simple code:

```js
let arr = [
  'bill-items',
  'bills',
  'customer-return-items',
  'customer-returns'
]

let re = new RegExp('^b*')

arr.forEach((e) => {
  console.log(`Matching ${e}: ` + re.test(e))
})
```

I expect two matches and two non-matches. Strangely I get four matches!
Check here: https://jsfiddle.net/kargirwar/gu7Lshnt/9/

What is happening?

Comment: You are asking the engine for *zero or more b's at the beginning* - which is always true when you think about it - use `^b+`

Comment: `b*` means *any number of "b", __including none__*.

Comment: I am a lifelong vimmer. I can't believe I asked this question. I don't even drink ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the "*" as following code snippets

> "*" matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

```js
let arr = [
  'bill-items',
  'bills',
  'customer-return-items',
  'customer-returns',
  'when-b-is-not-the-first-character',
  'b',
  '' //empty string
]

let re = new RegExp('^b')

arr.forEach((e) => {
  console.log(`Matching ${e}: ` + re.test(e))
})
```

The above code will match any strings that starts with letter b

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple

- `^`. matches the beginning of the string. Each of the four strings has a beginning
- `b*` matches any number of `b` also zero

And so, the regex matches the biggest part of the string it can. This is `^b` for the first two strings and just `^` for the others.

If you want to match only strings that begin with at least one `b` use `/^b+/` as the `+` requires at least one occurrence.

BTW you can use for instance https://regex101.com/ to test your regex and visualize the matches.